# How to get IWebBrowser2's update rect?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using IWebBrowser2 control to convert html into a bitmap in a win32 program, which I have succeeded doing it. I Draw the whole page all the time, which is not efficient way to do.

So it will be very good to know the update area, so that each time I can only draw the update rect. But I have not found any way to do so.

I did rendering flash before, and I can get dirty rect from IOleInPlaceSiteWindowless::InvalidateRect(LPCRECT pRect, BOOL), while IWebBrowser does have a window and does not have this interface.

What to do to get the dirty rect? Thank you inadvance!!

Answer (score 0):

I think [GetUpdateRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the function you are looking for. It returns the currently invalidate region.

Comment: What if invalidate regions are more than 1, and I can only get the latest one. Then I will lose other regions information, since it becomes from callback function mechanism to active call, some how.

Comment: GetUpdateRgn returns a region that covers all the invalidate regions.